# Workaround for Scala Error: The command line is too long?

Tags: windows, scala

I'm trying to compile someone's mod of minecraft so that I can make some changes to it. It uses scala somewhere in the recompiling, and I get this error:

```
== ERRORS FOUND in SCALA CODE ==

The command line is too long.
================================
```

I tend to agree:

```
'"scalac.bat" -encoding UTF-8 -deprecation -target:jvm-1.6 -classpath "jars\vers
ions\1.8.1\1.8.1.jar;lib;lib\*;lib;lib\*;jars\bin\minecraft.jar;jars\bin\jinput.
jar;jars\bin\lwjgl.jar;jars\bin\lwjgl_util.jar;jars\libraries\net\java\jinput\ji
nput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;jars\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.9.1\
lwjgl-platform-2.9.1-natives-windows.jar;jars\libraries\com\ibm\icu\icu4j-core-m
ojang\51.2\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;jars\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch-external-p
latform\4.5\twitch-external-platform-4.5-natives-windows-64.jar;jars\libraries\c
om\sixense\SixenseJavaLibrary\062612.0\SixenseJavaLibrary-062612.0-natives-windo
ws.jar;jars\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.3.2\httpcore-4.3.2.ja
r;jars\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.0-beta9\log4j-api-2.0-beta
9.jar;jars\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.3.2\commons-lang3-3.3.2.
jar;jars\libraries\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;jars\libraries\
com\paulscode\libraryjavasound\20101123\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;jars\libra
ries\net\sf\jopt-simple\jopt-simple\4.6\jopt-simple-4.6.jar;jars\libraries\com\g
oogle\guava\guava\17.0\guava-17.0.jar;jars\libraries\commons-logging\commons-log
ging\1.1.3\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;jars\libraries\org\apache\commons\commons-c
ompress\1.8.1\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;jars\libraries\com\sixense\SixenseJava\
062612.1\SixenseJava-062612.1.jar;jars\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch\6.5\twitch-6.5
.jar;jars\libraries\com\paulscode\codecjorbis\20101023\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;
jars\libraries\optifine\OptiFine\1.8.1_HD_U_B2\OptiFine-1.8.1_HD_U_B2.jar;jars\l
ibraries\com\paulscode\soundsystem\20120107\soundsystem-20120107.jar;jars\librar
ies\org\json\json\20140107\json-20140107.jar;jars\libraries\com\paulscode\librar
ylwjglopenal\20100824\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;jars\libraries\org\lwjgl\l
wjgl\lwjgl_util\2.9.1\lwjgl_util-2.9.1.jar;jars\libraries\commons-codec\commons-
codec\1.9\commons-codec-1.9.jar;jars\libraries\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcli
ent\4.3.3\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;jars\libraries\de\fruitfly\ovr\JRiftLibrary\0.4.4
.1\JRiftLibrary-0.4.4.1-natives-windows.jar;jars\libraries\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl
\2.9.1\lwjgl-2.9.1.jar;jars\libraries\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.j
ar;jars\libraries\com\mojang\realms\1.7.4\realms-1.7.4.jar;jars\libraries\net\ai
b42\mumblelink\JMumbleLibrary\1.1\JMumbleLibrary-1.1-natives-windows.jar;jars\li
braries\com\mojang\authlib\1.5.17\authlib-1.5.17.jar;jars\libraries\com\google\c
ode\gson\gson\2.2.4\gson-2.2.4.jar;jars\libraries\net\minecraft\launchwrapper\1.
7\launchwrapper-1.7.jar;jars\libraries\com\paulscode\codecwav\20101023\codecwav-
20101023.jar;jars\libraries\tv\twitch\twitch-platform\6.5\twitch-platform-6.5-na
tives-windows-64.jar;jars\libraries\net\java\jinput\jinput-platform\2.0.5\jinput
-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar;jars\libraries\de\fruitfly\ovr\JRift\0.4.4.1
\JRift-0.4.4.1.jar;jars\libraries\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-core\2.0-beta9\
log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;jars\libraries\net\aib42\mumblelink\JMumble\1.0\JMumble
-1.0.jar;jars\libraries\io\netty\netty-all\4.0.23.Final\netty-all-4.0.23.Final.j
ar" -sourcepath src\minecraft -d bin\minecraft src\minecraft\*.java src\minecraf
t\net\minecraft\block\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\block\material\*.java s
rc\minecraft\net\minecraft\block\properties\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\b
lock\state\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\block\state\pattern\*.java src\min
ecraft\net\minecraft\client\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\audio\*.ja
va src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\entity\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\
client\gui\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\gui\achievement\*.java src\
minecraft\net\minecraft\client\gui\inventory\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\
client\gui\spectator\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\gui\spectator\cat
egories\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\gui\stream\*.java src\minecraf
t\net\minecraft\client\main\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\model\*.ja
va src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\multiplayer\*.java src\minecraft\net\minec
raft\client\network\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\particle\*.java sr
c\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\player\inventory\*.java src\minecraft\net\minec
raft\client\renderer\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\renderer\block\mo
del\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\renderer\block\statemap\*.java src
\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\renderer\chunk\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraf
t\client\renderer\culling\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\renderer\ent
ity\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\renderer\entity\layers\*.java src\
minecraft\net\minecraft\client\renderer\texture\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecra
ft\client\renderer\tileentity\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\renderer
\vertex\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\resources\*.java src\minecraft
\net\minecraft\client\resources\data\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\r
esources\model\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\settings\*.java src\min
ecraft\net\minecraft\client\shader\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\str
eam\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\client\util\*.java src\minecraft\net\mine
craft\command\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\command\common\*.java src\minec
raft\net\minecraft\command\server\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\crash\*.jav
a src\minecraft\net\minecraft\creativetab\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\dis
penser\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\enchantment\*.java src\minecraft\net\m
inecraft\entity\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\entity\ai\*.java src\minecraf
t\net\minecraft\entity\ai\attributes\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\entity\b
oss\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\entity\effect\*.java src\minecraft\net\mi
necraft\entity\item\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\entity\monster\*.java src
\minecraft\net\minecraft\entity\passive\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\entit
y\player\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\entity\projectile\*.java src\minecra
ft\net\minecraft\event\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\init\*.java src\minecr
aft\net\minecraft\inventory\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\item\*.java src\m
inecraft\net\minecraft\item\crafting\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\nbt\*.ja
va src\minecraft\net\minecraft\network\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\networ
k\handshake\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\network\handshake\client\*.java s
rc\minecraft\net\minecraft\network\login\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\netw
ork\login\client\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\network\login\server\*.java
src\minecraft\net\minecraft\network\play\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\netw
ork\play\client\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\network\play\server\*.java sr
c\minecraft\net\minecraft\network\status\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\netw
ork\status\client\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\network\status\server\*.jav
a src\minecraft\net\minecraft\pathfinding\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\pot
ion\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\profiler\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecra
ft\realms\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\scoreboard\*.java src\minecraft\net
\minecraft\server\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\server\gui\*.java src\minec
raft\net\minecraft\server\integrated\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\server\m
anagement\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\server\network\*.java src\minecraft
\net\minecraft\src\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\stats\*.java src\minecraft
\net\minecraft\tileentity\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\util\*.java src\min
ecraft\net\minecraft\village\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\world\*.java src
\minecraft\net\minecraft\world\biome\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\world\bo
rder\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\world\chunk\*.java src\minecraft\net\min
ecraft\world\chunk\storage\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\world\demo\*.java
src\minecraft\net\minecraft\world\gen\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\world\g
en\feature\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\world\gen\layer\*.java src\minecra
ft\net\minecraft\world\gen\structure\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\world\pa
thfinder\*.java src\minecraft\net\minecraft\world\storage\*.java src\minecraft\o
ptifine\*.java src\minecraft\optifine\json\*.java' failed : 1
```

Given that windows has a character limit on the command line.

I'm using windows 8.1 and scala 2.11.0.

I was wondering, is there a way to set this as an environment/path variable or something to avoid this?

What would I have to change? I'm very new to messing around with system stuff like this, but I think I know where scala is called in the scripts and this argument is given. If that helps.

Comment: Well...... I am at loss of words.... So how were you compiling the code ? Was it using some build tool like sbt, maven, gradle or was it using Make ? Whatever the case... can you provide the build file or Makefile... ?

Answer (score 1):

`scalac` accepts an `@file` parameter containing a file with arguments in. So if you can modify whatever script is calling `scalac.bat` to instead put the arguments in a temporary file `arguments.txt` and then call `scalac @arguments.txt` that should work.